# Prevent Windows Vista from restarting/shutting down, ever

Tags: windows-vista, shutdown, reboot

I have running a desktop computer as a server ATM for personal reasons. I don't have physical access to the computer, I can only access it through Teamviewer. The computer is multiboot, with the default **not** set to Vista. This means that if/when the computer restarts I don't have access to it anymore. This has happened twice now, and is a pain in the ass (for both me and the people that have to restart it manually). I have no idea what the cause of the restart is, it might be automatic updates or a 3rd party program.

How can I prevent a Windows Vista computer from restarting/shutting down by software means? (obviously pulling the plug will shut the computer down)

Comment: You might also think about setting the computer to boot to Vista by default. You can only gain from doing it.

Comment: @satuon: Taken out of context that sounds hilarious. But seriously, I don't want to bother the people at which the computer resides with this. When I get physical access to the computer again (this will be at least 2 weeks) I will set it to Windows Vista by default.

Comment: Have you disabled Automatic Updates? Most common reason for spontanious reboots :)

Comment: @satuon: I haven't (yet), but I want to treat the problem more extensively :)

Comment: You won't be able to entirely prevent restarts - in particular there is no way to prevent a restart (or halt) in the event of a `blue screen` kernel exception.  For windows updates, rather than disabling them entirely, set the options to 'download and notify' rather than 'download and install' - that way you can control when you install critical security fixes.

Comment: You can modify boot menu to make Vista the first ( default ) choice through a remote connection.

Comment: @Ramhound: but not GRUB...